# Javascript (client-side): Database query and Data handling

Tags: javascript

I have built a web application that accepts a Member_ID # from the client (javascript). The Member_ID is stored as a var in my javascript… now I need to make queries with it…first query to get member information (name) and then join tables to gather information for health plans that the member is elligible under … and so on.

As far as I can remember the concept is… send a async request to the server and wait for a response, once the response is received, store it and then parse it to extract useful information.

The end goal is to use the 'useful' information to plot graphs using HTML5 Canvas.

I need some direction with how to make the query? because when I read this forum, it is recommended that client-side query is 'bad' for a plethora of reasons.

Since most of my stuff is happening in the client side... few things in C# asp.net...how do I proceed?

It is also important to note that the web application should be accessible via the internet. outside the local network.

**Does it make sense to Call a Web Service from the Client Side Using the AJAX Extension Toolkit??**

Comment: "join tables" is a task that should happen serverside.

Comment: why is it server side specific? and if it is then how can i relate the information back to my client side..since my canvas nd graph plotting functionalities are on the client side. HTML5 canvas javascript

Comment: Be careful about trusting the member id from your form -- validate, or better store it in the server session.  Why?  What happens if someone changes the member id using a forms editor or developer tool?  Can they get data they shouldn't?

Comment: Your API (i.e., what you're calling via AJAX requests) should do all the data work and then send back the results to the client for presentation.

Comment: The MemberID can be trusted because there is a log in security process before the web application is accessible. The URL is not public.. but under a domain. However I can see how developer tools can be used to inject/falsify Mem_ID's

Comment: Xophmeister - can you please elaborate ? or show me a link ? I would appreciate this very much... I need to read a formalized definitive manual/example.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term API. Basically the steps you need to take are:  validate form data, extract your form data and put it in an object, do an AJAX request using the data to your backend handler file (asp), generate query based on parameters received, execute, generate server output to screen based on query results, handle response in client side.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin! Could elaborate on the 2nd last step = "generate server output to screen based on query result"... what is the signifcance of this step?? Once query is executed and store in some form of data container..then it should be returned to the client side and then handled accordingly... maybe I am not understanding what you mean

Comment: You need to let the client know if the query was successful or not.  What if lets say the record was a duplicate and the query fails. How will the user know? You need to send some sort of data back to the client.

Comment: Thanks. Does this process have a definitive name? As in, if I had to do more research nd reading on this topic..what would I "google"?

Comment: You can look at the links in my answer they provide samples using php you just need to do the same thing in asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle it server side. Think about the ajax request as a simple POST or GET in the format of `?member_id=123&time=321` pointed at your handler file.

In your handler file you can construct your query from the request variables, execute it, and give a response by printing to the screen in either JSON or XML format.

Take a look here:

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/